# spring-cloud-dataflow register custom module from local repository

Tags: spring-cloud, aether, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have a jar with parent spring-cloud-dataflow-parent, which I register using my local repository --coordinates. But once I execute module info on it, I receive this error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact ... in repository 1 (https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot)
This open issue does not seem the same: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/191

It looks like the AetherModuleResolver does not find my module which is in ~/.m2/repository... and fallback on the default repository.

I have tried to modify .../springframework/cloud/dataflow/admin/config/AdminProperties.java for testing but without success

I have tried to modify the default reposiroty in ~/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-stream-module-launcher/1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT$ vi META-INF/spring-configuration-metadata.json but without success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matt: Apologies for the delayed response.

Since your attempt registering custom applications in Spring Cloud Data Flow, we have made a lot of improvements. Currently, there's support to register custom applications from `maven`, `http`, `classpath`, `file-system` or as `docker` artifacts. The documentation [PR](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/pull/498) will be merged soon.

Please try the latest and let us know if you notice any other issues and/or feedback.

Comment: Thanks, I continued dev on SpringXD, and will be going to spring cloud data flow in the future.